# After integrating Git-For-Windows, I'm getting this error at MSYS2 startup: bash: create-shortcut.exe: command not found

Tags: windows, git-bash, msys2

I installed `msys2`, and then integrated the installation of `Git-For-Windows` within that `msys2` environment, by applying [this simple procedure](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Install-inside-MSYS2-proper).

After doing so, I'm getting this error when I double-click the `msys2` desktop icon:

```
bash: create-shortcut.exe: command not found
bash: create-shortcut.exe: command not found

jdoe@msys2$
```

I can see where the above error originates.

The aforementioned procedure created this new script - `/etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh` - which attempts to run the `create-shortcut.exe` command; but (like the script) I can't find where `create-shortcut.exe` is.

Does anyone know where that `create-shortcut.exe` comes from (`MSYS2`, `MS-WINDOWS`), or where it might be located? Or perhaps even know what the fix for this is? =:)

Comment: That's not a Windows tool. Stands to reason it's from MSYS2

Comment: What's the point of that procedure? Can't you just install the `git` package from MSYS2?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not without it (you need to add repositories and do other things). In the end, I simply disabling that `sh` script because it wasn't doing anything important. `git` is working fine. :)

Comment: Git exists in the default repos, you don't have to use custom ones.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I was not aware of that. I'm new to MSYS2 and am trying to create a Linux-ish CLI, which is what I normally work in. Thie is good to know. Maybe I'll back out the above and install the one in default repo. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't related to Git itself, but I have no idea what `create-shortcut.exe` is intended to do.

Comment: This is more of a question for SuperUser StackExchange community than for StackOverflow. Just FYI.

Comment: Yes, this is true (and I almost went there instead). I'll answer this and close it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to the commenters.

It's a bug, either because the referenced command wasn't included in the package, or because the command is not in the script's `PATH`. I'll file an issue in the `GitHub` project for it.

Thank you particularly to `@HolyBlackCat` for pointing out that the procedure wasn't necessary since `git(1)` is already available in `MSYS2`s default repositories. (I'm new to `MSYS2` because I was provided a `Windows` environment instead of `Linux`). So, I ended up backing out the procedure and installing the native repository version instead, which works well.

However, if you did want to keep the version provided by the procedure -- because it does, indeed, offer more than just the `git(1)` command (e.g., it has an `SDK` too) -- then you can simply locate and safely comment-out the offending section in the `/etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh` RC script, whose only purpose is to create a `Windows` desktop icon. Hopefully this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error will not pop up when you launch `C:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe` and it will create itself as shortcut on the desktop, that's what the lines do. You probably try to use the Windows terminal with the init command `C:\git-sdk-64\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i` and the icon `C:\git-sdk-64\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico`.

Editing `/etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh` isn't the best idea. It would've been better to adjust the user's `.bash_profile` to include the `PATH` to `create-shortcut.exe`, but putting `export PATH="/mingw64/bin:$PATH"` into the file doesn't help, because `create-shortcut.exe` is called even earlier.

It seems `/etc/profile` loads `git-sdk.sh` and the `git-bash.exe` wrapper that you skip is setting `PATH="/mingw64/bin:$PATH` to make `create-shortcut.exe` work, I think.

Luckily by the time `git-sdk.sh` is sourced the `PATH` already contains `/usr/local/bin`, so you can just symlink the exe to that path via an Admin shell:

```bash
MSYS="winsymlinks:nativestrict"
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
ln -s /mingw64/bin/create-shortcut.exe /usr/local/bin/
```

Now the error is gone in any Terminal without touching any shell scripts.